# Sufficient condition implying that all surjections onto trivial irrep must split

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $ G $ a Lie group. Consider a short exact sequence of finite dimensional $ \mathbb{C}[G] $ modules.
$$
0 \to W \to V \to \mathbb{C} \to 0
$$
What is a sufficient condition on $ G $ to imply that all sequences of this form must split?

For example if $ G $ is a compact group then every irrep of $ G $ is completely reducible so if $ V/W $ is a trivial 1d irrep then some complement $ W^\perp $ exists and is a trivial 1d subrep of $ V $ and the sequence splits.

I'm especially interested in what situations this would fail. So it would be especially interesting to have an example of a group $ G $ and a SES of continuous finite dimensional $ \mathbb{C}[G] $ modules
$$
0 \to W \to V \to \mathbb{C} \to 0
$$
that doesn't split.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez ok I added that $ V $ should be finite dimensional and I want all SES of this form to split

Comment: When $G$ is a finite group this depends on the field of coefficients of the vector spaces appearing in your SES. More precisely, it always works in characteristic zero, but does not work if the characteristic of the field is a factor of the order of the group.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Ok that's fair! I've edited the question to add Lie group and complex. I'm mostly interested in characteristic $ 0 $ and continuous representation of Lie groups, although algebraic representations of algebraic group are also good because they are pretty similar. But I certainly wouldn't mind any fun facts about the positive characteristic case, or general topological groups or something like that, it's always good to expand my horizons!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Ah I see I should have thought to look around using the word projective. So if I understand https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3959178/trivial-group-representation-is-projective-implies-semisimple then this property should be true for all reductive Lie groups/ algebraic groups, basically because if $ V $ is completely reducible then the SES must split?

Comment: Given the comments, there’s an obvious situation where the exact sequence fails to split (which somehow wasn’t spelled out)? Take $G=\mathbb{C}$, acting (by $\star$) on $V=\mathbb{C}x \oplus \mathbb{C}y$, where $G$ acts trivially on $W=\mathbb{C}x$, and $g \star y=gx+y$ for $g \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I've attempted to answer my own question using your comments, does it seem right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is:

Let $ G $ a Lie group. Consider a short exact sequence of finite dimensional $ \mathbb{C}[G] $ modules.
$$
0 \to W \to V \to \mathbb{C} \to 0
$$
What is a sufficient condition on $ G $ to imply that all sequences of this form must split?

Some sufficient conditions are:

- $ G $ is compact
- $ G $ is the complex points of a linear algebraic group whose real points are compact https://math.stackexchange.com/a/218039/758507
- $ G $ is semisimple https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_theorem_on_complete_reducibility

In summary, I believe that for a Lie group $ G $, all short exact sequences of the form described above split if and only if $ G $ is linearly reductive (i.e. the category of finite dimensional complex representation of $ G $ is semisimple) if and only if $ G $ is semisimple or compact or the complexification of a compact group or isogeneous to a direct product of groups of these three types.

As for examples of short exact sequence of this form that do not split:

Aphelli points out that unipotent groups are an easy source of examples of Lie groups with complex representations that are reducible but indecomposable, and such representation are never semisimple.

Consider the abelian unipotent group
$$
G:=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and its natural two dimensional representation $ V $
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} x+by \\ y \end{bmatrix}
$$
There is a one dimensional trivial subrepresentation, call it $ W $,
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} x \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
which is the kernel of the homomorphism $ \pi: V \to \mathbb{C} $ given by $ \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} \mapsto y $. (The representation $ V $ is not semisimple, see for example the proof given here [Show that the only subrepresentation of $A$ is $W= \{(t,0) \mid t \in \Bbb R\}$. So $V$ is not reducible, but it is indecomposable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4841232/show-that-the-only-subrepresentation-of-a-is-w-t-0-mid-t-in-bbb-r) or here [Indecomposable but not irreducible representation and direct sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2484809/indecomposable-but-not-irreducible-representation-and-direct-sums))

So we have a short exact sequence
$$
0 \to W \to V \to \mathbb{C} \to 0
$$
which does not split because any embedding $ s: \mathbb{C} \to V $ would have to have image $ W $, since that is the only 1d subrepresentation, but then it would not be a splitting because $ \pi(s(\mathbb{C}))=\pi(W)=0 $.